# missing / RegEx code

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to append the script to the page but I get the answer:

Invalid regular expression: missing /

Can someone please take a look and show me where is the problem in my RegEx code?

```
function init(){

var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = 'jx = {'+
'b: function () {'+
    'var b = !1;'+
    'if ("undefined" != typeof ActiveXObject) { try {'+
            'b = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");'+
       ' } catch (c) {'+
           ' try {'+
              '  b = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");'+
           ' } catch (a) {'+
              '  b = !1;'+
          '  }'+
      '  } } else { if (window.XMLHttpRequest) try {'+
         '   b = new XMLHttpRequest;'+
        '} catch (h) {'+
         '   b = !1;'+
       ' }'+
        '}'+
       ' return b;'+

  '  },'+
'load: function (b, c, a, h, g) {'+
   ' var e = this.d();'+
   ' if (e && b) {'+
      '  e.overrideMimeType && e.overrideMimeType("text/xml");'+
       ' h || (h = "GET");'+
      '  a || (a = "text");'+
      '  g || (g = {});'+
       ' a = a.toLowerCase();'+
       ' h = h.toUpperCase();'+
      '  b += b.indexOf("?") + 1 ? "&" : "?";'+
      '  var k = null;'+
     '   "POST" == h && (k = b.split("?"), b = k[0], k = k[1]);'+
      '  e.open(h, b, !0);'+
      '  e.onreadystatechange = g.c ? function () {'+
      '      g.c(e)'+
        '} : function () {'+
         '   if (4 == e.readyState)'+
            '    if (200 == e.status) {'+
               '     var b = "";'+
                '    e.responseText && (b = e.responseText);'+
                 '   "j" == a.charAt(0) ? (b = b.replace(/[\n\r]/g, ""), b = eval("(" + b + ")")) : "x" == a.charAt(0) && (b = e.responseXML);'+
                 '   c && c(b)'+
               ' } else g.f && document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(g.f), g.e && (document.getElementById(g.e).style.display = "none"), error && error(e.status)'+
       ' };'+
      '  e.send(k);'+
   ' }'+
'},'+
' d: function () {'+
   ' return this.b()'+
' }'+
'};'+
'alert("loaded");';

document.body.appendChild(script);

}
```

Do you see a mistake!

Comment: 1) Yes your using strings 2) that is not a regex

Comment: `\n` inside a regex inside a string is still an actual newline character.

Comment: Just alert(script.text) to see the problem, then change to `b.replace(/[\\n\\r]/g, "")` and alert again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite apart from what you're doing, the problem is that you're not escaping the backslashes. the reges

```
/[\n\r]/g
```

By itself is perfectly fine, but you're not writing a literal RegExp instance, you're writing a string. In a string `\n` is an escape sequence for a new line. To get around this, escape the backslash:

```
var str = '/[\\n\\r]/g';
```

would do the trick